# SQL Searching entries not yet grouped

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

```
+------- IPs ------+  +---- Groups ---+
| Id (Int)         |  | Id (Int)      |
| IP (String)      |  | Name (String) |
| Comment (String) |  | IPs (String)  |
+------------------+  +---------------+
```

The `IPs`-column of `Groups` is a comma-separated list of the IPS that this group consists of (The `Id` of the IP in the `IPs`-table of course).

I now want to find all `IPs` that have not yet been grouped -> No reference in any `Group`s `IPs`-field.

My idea was to somehow join all the `Groups.IPs` together and then search for all the `IPs.IP`s that are not in that list.

I'd really love to get that done completely in SQL (Programmatically is not the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's some hacky solution to your problem, but if you want to "get that done completely in SQL", I suggest refactoring your tables to avoid the comma-separated list of Ids. For a list of problems that comma-separated fields attract, I suggest checking out this recent Stack Overflow post:

- [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/222908)

I suggest a table schema that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ips (
   id int,
   ip varchar(255),
   comment varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
   id int,
   name varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ip_groups (
   group_id int,
   ip_id int,
   PRIMARY KEY (ip_id, group_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES ips(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (ip_id) REFERENCES groups(id)
);
```

Then your query could be as easy as this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ips
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                   FROM ip_groups 
                   WHERE ip_groups.ip_id = ips.id);
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO ips VALUES (1, '127.0.0.1', 'localhost');
INSERT INTO ips VALUES (2, '10.0.0.1', 'router');
INSERT INTO ips VALUES (3, '10.0.0.100', 'my macbook');

INSERT INTO groups VALUES (1, '10.0.0 subnet');
INSERT INTO groups VALUES (2, 'computers');

INSERT INTO ip_groups VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO ip_groups VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO ip_groups VALUES (2, 3);
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | ip        | comment   |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | 127.0.0.1 | localhost |
+----+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `127.0.0.1` IP does not belog to any group.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can also solve the above by using the "null-self-join" method:

```
SELECT     ips.id, ips.ip, ips.comment
FROM       ips
LEFT JOIN  ip_groups ON (ip_groups.ip_id = ips.id)
WHERE      ip_groups.group_id IS NULL;
```

This is normally faster than the previous solution, because it does not use a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). The problem with correlated subqueries is that they are executed once for each row in the outer query, and therefore performance suffers when the outer query (`SELECT * FROM ips` in this case) returns many rows.